# A Word for Someone Who Watch Sports

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage

I am looking for a specific word for someone who watch only games of sports? I know he is a spectator but it is too broad to fit in what I am looking for. It is not audience too. Someone who watch games and not events other than games.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 3):

There are lots of terms: sports fan, sports fanatic, sports aficionado, sports enthusiast, sports spectator.  None of those, however, indicate that he watches only sports and nothing else.  There isn't a term for that.  If you want to say something to that effect, you'd say something like, "He's faithfully married to sports spectating, never having a wandering eye."